# ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2) when using seaborn

Tags: python, numpy, data-visualization, seaborn

I am trying to plot a count plot using seaborn. However, I keep getting the error:

```
 ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)
```

The data is in array format like this:

```
      kmeans_updated_transform 
Output : array([[  69.86249185,  420.73371599,  293.97930338, ...,   75.0959945 ,
            1324.91605382,  695.82952194],
           [ 653.72679905,  173.0166009 ,  881.79444099, ...,  519.62763564,
             737.738956  ,  114.53013382],
           [ 137.60270124,  621.0421363 ,   93.48686268, ...,  271.48007915,
            1525.69688999,  896.4147582 ],
           ...,


pca_original_transform
Output: array([[ 9.43214091e+01, -1.89435531e+01,  1.07357663e+01, ...,
         1.23508040e-02, -4.93779143e-03,  4.85990628e-13],
       [ 6.82436757e+02,  3.43334711e+01,  9.96130809e+00, ...,
         1.91267574e-02,  8.14910013e-03, -1.38680181e-13],
       [-1.06579511e+02, -6.68715037e+00, -1.84056983e+00, ...,
        -1.90794427e-02, -4.22592696e-03, -2.87145744e-13],
       ...,
```

Finally, I have a data frame known as cat. 
This is the code I am using

```
ax = sns.countplot(x=pca_orignal_transform, hue=kmeans_updated_transform, data=cat)
```

Why is the count plot throwing an error when I try to plot it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you show the code or part of the code where the exception occurs?

Comment: @Shiva I just updated the code in the question.

Comment: Please check if you have duplicate column names in your `cat` dataframe.

Comment: You may want to read [mcve] and provide such example, such that others have a chance to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If `df` is your dataframe, a countplot is produced by supplying the column names from that dataframe to the arguments of `countplot`

```
ax = sns.countplot(x="columnname1", hue="columnname2", data=cat)
```

Comment: ok what if I wish to use the arrays only and not the df it doesn't work why is that? @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: But if you look at the parameter `data` on the [countplot-documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html). It says it can take an array, dataframe or list of arrays... @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: Yes, `data` can be an array. But `hue` cannot, if `data` is given.

Comment: ok I am plotting clusters data using the pca data from seen from the name of the arrays how can I do that any suggestions which type of countplot to use ? @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: Well, of course my suggestion would be to use the answer I provided here.

Comment: But I have to plot the data with the arrays. Forget the df @ ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: Use a dataframe that contains the arrays you want to plot, not some other dataframe.